# scala automated resource management continuations issue

Tags: scala

Recently trying to upgrade some oldish Scala code to use the Scala ARM library, in particular I like the continuations approach.

My code is throwing a java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on the resource.ManagedResource.managed object.

Here is my code:

```
val conn = managed(ConnectionPool.getConnection()) !
```

Where ConnectionPool.getConnection returns a java.sql.Connection to my database, the connection pool is based on BoneCP and works fine without using managed.

This line of code returns the errors:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: resource.ManagedResource.$banf()Ljava/lang/object;
```

Any help much appreciated. It's starting to seem I should just create my own ARM library as it's obviously very easy. However I do prefer to use community projects for my team's ease of future maitenance.

I should add that BoneCP is not the cause and the same error is returned when I create the connection manually.

Thanks
Rich

Comment: I suspect you have a different version of scala-arm on your runtime CLASSPATH.

Comment: OK Thanks Robin, that seems to have been an issue. Now I am getting an error that "found cps expression in non-cps position" however.